# Installing sonar plugin on jenkins

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

I want to install sonar plugin on jenkins, for this I have installed sonar(version-3.2) and jenkins(version 1.464) on my machine and both of these tools are running.
For installing sonar-jenkins plugin, I go to Jenkins Home-->Manage Jenkins-->Manage Plugins-->Available..
Here in the available tab I have found sonar plugin-2.1 which is not compatible to my installed jenkins-1.464(plugin also showing warning--"This plugin is built for Jenkins 1.491 or newer. It may or may not work in your Jenkins.") here, I need to install sonar plugin-1.8 successfully on my installed jenkins.
What should I do to find sonar plugin-1.8 in my jenkins available tab??OR
is there any way to degrade sonar pluign-2.1 to sonar plugin-1.8??
If anybody knows anything on this please respond.
Your revert will be appreciable..
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Jenkins 1.464 is now 12 months old... I think it's time to upgrade, or stop installing new plugins. No easy answer on this one.

Answer (score 2):

Is there anything preventing you from upgrading Jenkins to version 1.491+? If not, you should really upgrade to make things easier.
Same question for Sonar. Is there anything preventing you from upgrading to version 3.5.1?

Thank you

David RACODON | SonarSource